# Getting 'Forbidden: unknown' Error When Bootstrapping Flux with GitLab and Terraform

Tags: terraform, gitlab, fluxcd

I am trying to bootstrap Flux with GitLab through Terraform in DigitalOcan, when I test it, I get this error message and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
│ Error: Bootstrap run error
│ 
│   with flux_bootstrap_git.this,
│   on flux.tf line 34, in resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this":
│   34: resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this" {
│ 
│ CustomResourceDefinition/alerts.notification.toolkit.fluxcd.io dry-run failed, reason: Forbidden: unknown
```

This is the code I have tried to run witch is the code provide by terraform and flux, which leads to this error message.

```
provider "flux" {
  kubernetes = {
    host                   = module.kubernetes.endpoint
    client_certificate     = module.kubernetes.client_certificate
    client_key             = module.kubernetes.client_key
    cluster_ca_certificate = module.kubernetes.cluster_ca_certificate
  }
  git = {
    url = "ssh://git@git.test.no/tekkom/infrastructure/kubernetes/external-prod-cluster"
    ssh = {
      username = "git"
      private_key = tls_private_key.flux.private_key_pem
    }
  }
}


resource "tls_private_key" "flux" {
  algorithm   = "ECDSA"
  ecdsa_curve = "P256"
}

data "gitlab_project" "this" {
  path_with_namespace = "tekkom/infrastructure/kubernetes/external-prod-cluster"
}

resource "gitlab_deploy_key" "this" {
  project  = data.gitlab_project.this.id
  title    = "Flux"
  key      = tls_private_key.flux.public_key_openssh
  can_push = true
}

resource "flux_bootstrap_git" "this" {
  depends_on = [gitlab_deploy_key.this]
  path       = "cluster/"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I had to remove the `client_certificate` and `client_key` and add the `token` so that the code ended up looking like this:

```
provider "flux" {
  kubernetes = {
    host                   = module.kubernetes.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = module.kubernetes.cluster_ca_certificate
    token = module.kubernetes.cluster_token
  }
  git = {
    url = "ssh://git@git.test.no/tekkom/infrastructure/kubernetes/external-prod-cluster"
    ssh = {
      username    = "git"
      private_key = tls_private_key.flux.private_key_pem
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks was exactly the issue I had as well!